# Age of Empires 3

Tags: games

How do electronic peasants like myself install Age of Empires 3 on ubuntu?  I have tried the wine website and attempted to install through wine already, but got stuck.  I am not a clued up person when it comes to computers.  Could someone please take me through this step by step?

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested in **0 A.D.**, which is a similar game available in the Ubuntu repository. Package name is `0ad`. Maybe you want to try that out in the meanwhile? :)

Comment: According the `wine` [Age of Empires III page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2441) you've got some chances of it running. But I don't use `wine` so can't give you more help than that...

Comment: "Could someone please take me through this step by step?" Sure but the better method would be to install vBox, Windows in vBox and AOE Windows edition in Windows. Or dual boot. Gettting it to work in Wine is a time waster and not a guarantee it will work to begin with or continue to work in the future. Besides that: the graphics will probably also be a disappointment.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29761 is the best one

Comment: Thanks,  Rinzwind, I am attempting it.  Will give feedback, once completed